# unable to Post a csv file on postMan

Tags: c#, .net-core, postman

I'm trying to import a csv file from postMan but I don't know what I miss I have that message error: The file field is required, even I upload the file. thank you for your help
[image]

Comment: Is the name of the key correct?

Comment: as @madmonk46 states i think you need to rename `key1` to `file`. Also make sure you aren't missing any other required fields

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue. My issue was solved by adding the key name to file.

[image: Screenshot]